# Simulating colspan (on ie >=8) by using display: table, table-row, table-cell

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tablelayout

I have to create a layout with two rows. The first row has one cell and the second one has three cells:

```
|     A     |
| B | C | D |
```

Is it possible by using divs, with css display property table, table-row and table-cell?

I succeeded in creating that layout by using two different table div (one for the first row and one for the second row), but so the border-spacing between the cells gives a bad effect: the spacing between the two rows is double of that one between the cells of the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the CSS table model is currently much simpler than the HTML table model. A CSS table is a simple grid, with no counterpart to `colspan` or `rowspan`.

There are many ways to achieve the desired layout, e.g. using CSS positioning.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd just like to caution people that table-layouts in general cannot be replicated with CSS positioning (well, pre `flex` or `grid` anyhow) because `table`'s, uniquely, auto-size their rows and columns *and have that inferred size applied to related elements too*.  In short: if you want to size a complex layout to it's content, just stick with tables.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne, right, but as the question seems to be about page layout design (rather than tabular data even in a broad sense), I would expect that the idea is to set the “cell” widths explicitly, in some units, instead of automatic table layout.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: So you suggest to set the width cell explicitly, for example in px, don't you? Or is it better to use html table (you're right, I need a page layout)

Comment: @Cricket, I wouldn’t suggest anything without seeing a concrete problem, and it would be a completely different question. And there are zillions of ways to do simple page layout.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I have 4 text boxes, each with a title, a text body and a link. The first box is in top with 100% width, while the other three boxes are in the second row.

Comment: @Cricket yeah that sounds like Jukka's suggestion to take a look at CSS positioning can help you.  However, if you want to go into detail, ask another question :-).